# Get FeedItem and TopicAssignment details from FeedComment

Tags: apex, soql, query, feeditem, feedcomment

I'm trying to build a query which would get all comments and the Topics assigned to the FeedItem they belong to but looks like I have hit a snag.

This is what I'm trying right now -->

```
SELECT Id, FeedItemId, ParentId, FeedItem.Title, CommentBody FROM FeedComment Limit 10
```

But I get this error -->

```
Didn't understand relationship 'FeedItem' in field path. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I want to be able to get the following fields in my result -- FeedItem.Title and the Topic(s) assigned to that FeedItem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can able to get `Feed Item` values based on `Feed Comment`, Since `Feed Item` is behave the std parent in here,

But You can use to query `Feed Item` and able to query `Feed comment`as a nested one as,

```
 List<FeedItem> feedItemlist =  SELECT Id, Title FROM FeedItem WHERE Id (SELECT FeedItemId FROM FeedComment LIMIT 10)
```

Which return the `FeedItem Id` required, After you can use that `feedItemlist` variable to form this `Map`

```
Map <Id, FeedItem> feedMap = new Map <Id, FeedItem>(feedItemlist);
```

After write a below query to get topic assigned for that feeditem (key of that Map),

```
SELECT Id, TopicId FROM TopicAssignment WHERE EntityId IN: feedMap.keySet())
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yeah thought so, I'll ultimately have to use some workarounds.